# Matching regex to list items in Python

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, nginx

I am attempting to write a python script that shows the URL flow on my installation of nginx. So I currently have my script opening my 'rewrites' file that contains a list of of regex's and locations like so:

```
rewritei ^/ungrad/info.cfm$ /ungrad/info/ permanent;
```

So what I currently have python doing is reading the file, trimming the first and last word off (rewritei and premanent;) which just leaves a list like so:

```
[
    ['^/ungrad/info.cfm$', '/ungrad/info'],
    ['^/admiss/testing.cfm$', '/admiss/testing'],
    ['^/ungrad/testing/$', '/ungrad/info.cfm']
]
```

This results in the first element being the URL watched, and the second being the URL redirected to. What I would like to do now, is take each of the first elements, and run the regex over the entire list, and check if it matches any of the second elements.

With the example above, [0][0] would match [2][1].

However I am having trouble thinking of a good and efficient way to do this.

Comment: Map [x][0] to a new array and run a loop to compile a RegEx for each string in the new array, then within the loop check the compiled RegEx against another mapped array from [x][1] and then keep track of the matches however you want. At least that's how I'd generally do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import re

a = [
    ['^/ungrad/info.cfm$', '/ungrad/info'],
    ['^/admiss/testing.cfm$', '/admiss/testing'],
    ['^/ungrad/testing/$', '/ungrad/info.cfm']
]



def matchingfun(b):
    for list1 in a: # iterating the main list
        for reglist in list1: # iterating the inner lists
            count  = 0
            matchedurl = []
            for innerlist in reglist[:1]: # iterating the inner list items
                c = b.match(innerlist) # matching the regx
                if c:
                    count = count+1
                    if count > 0:
                        matchedurl.append(reglist)
    return matchedurl

result1 = []
for list1 in a:
    for reglist in list1:
        b = re.compile(reglist[0])
        result = matchingfun(b)
        result1.extend(result)

bs = list(set(result1))

print "matched url is", bs
```

This is bit unefficient i guess but I have done to some extent. Hope this answers your query. the above snippet prints the urls which are matched with the second items in the entire list.

Comment: That is similar to what I came up with, and the inefficiency is exactly what I'm worried about too. Hopefully the dataset we are working with won't be to large and cause any significant issues.